# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined - Vue and building as Web Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've built my very small vue app with the `--target wc` command which creates a web component. I host my component.js file using Google CDN and then import it in the HTML-page in the head using

then enter the  in the HTML file as supposed to.

But I get the above error with the vuex store when the page first loads - then it connects to the server (i'm using socket.io) as it's supposed to.

Here's the store:

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        insiderTrades: [],
    },

    mutations: {
        ADD_INSIDER_TRADE(state, insiderData) {
            //create the insiderObject
            const insiderObject = {
                pubDate: insiderData[0],
                publisher: insiderData[1],
                person: insiderData[2],
                role: insiderData[3],
                relative: insiderData[4],
                type: insiderData[5],
                instrument: insiderData[6],
                isin: insiderData[7],
                transDate: insiderData[8],
                volume: insiderData[9],
                qtyUnit: insiderData[10],
                price: insiderData[11],
                currency: insiderData[12],
                market: insiderData[13],
            };

            if (state.insiderTrades.length === 0) {
                // push object into array
                state.insiderTrades.unshift(insiderObject);
            } else {
                state.insiderTrades.forEach((trade) => {
                    // check if the insider trade is in the store
                    if (trade.isin === insiderData[7]) {
                        // return if it already exists
                        return;
                    } else {
                        // push object into array
                        state.insiderTrades.unshift(insiderObject);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
    },
    getters: {
        getInsiderTrades(state) {
            return state.insiderTrades;
        },
    },
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
});
```

Here is the main vue component accessing the store:

```
<template>
    <div class="app-container">
        <div class="connected-state">
            <div :class="`badge --badge-${connectedStateColor}`"></div>
            <div class="state-text">{{ connectedState }}</div>
        </div>
        <insider-trade
            v-for="trade in insiderTrades"
            :insiderData="trade"
        ></insider-trade>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import InsiderTrade from './components/InsiderTrade';
    import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            InsiderTrade,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                connectedState: '',
                connectedStateColor: '',
                insiderTrades: this.$store.getters.getInsiderTrades,
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            //intialize the socket plugin
            const socketUrl = {
                local: 'http://localhost:5000',
                devOps:
                    'https://sweden-daytraders-devops.herokuapp.com/',
                production: 'https://sweden-daytraders.herokuapp.com/',
            };
            const socket = io(socketUrl.production);
            //establish connection to server
            socket.on('connect', () => {
                this.connectedState = 'connected';
                this.connectedStateColor = 'green';
                console.log('Connected to server');
            });
            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                this.connectedState = 'disconnected';
                this.connectedStateColor = 'red';
                console.log('Disconnected to server');
            });
            socket.on('insiderTrade', (insiderData) => {
                this.$store.commit('ADD_INSIDER_TRADE', insiderData);
            });
        },
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @use "@/assets/main.scss";
</style>
```

Also here is the log from console in chrome:

[image]

Comment: Instead of accessing getters like this, try using `mapGetters`: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error. When I run the app during development and hot module reloading I get no errors and everything works fine. But once i decide to build the app and do that as a web component I get the error. Doesn't matter if I host the js-file at a CDN or run the web component locally. Error is there...

Comment: This proved to be the solution for the error -> https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2304#issuecomment-414682432